# Add None dimension in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor `xx` with shape:

```
>>> xx.shape
TensorShape([32, 32, 256])
```

How can I add a leading `None` dimension to get:

```
>>> xx.shape
TensorShape([None, 32, 32, 256])
```

I have seen many answers here but all are related to TF 1.x

What is the straight forward way for TF 2.0?

Comment: Does the first dimension have to be `None`? You can easily add a singleton dimension with `xx[tf.newaxis]` or `tf.expand_dims(xx, 0)`. In general, there are not many ways of "erasing" known shape information, specially if you are in eager mode where tensors are not symbolic. If you need `None`, what is the reason?

Comment: @jdehesa this is requied during by TF graph creation, the first dimension is `None` since its represents batch size. I am trying to implement a layer by myself: For example I want to take a tensor shaped `(None, 32,32, 512)` and to sum every four channels into one channel `yy[:,:,:,0] = sum(xx[:,:,:,0:16:4]), yy[:,:,:,1] = sum(xx[:,:,:,1:17:4])...`

Answer (score 2):

You can either use "None" or numpy's "newaxis" to create the new dimension.

**General Tip:** You can also use None in place of np.newaxis; These are in fact the [same objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

Below is the code that explains both the options.

```
try:
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)

# TensorFlow and tf.keras
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np

#### Import the Fashion MNIST dataset
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

#Original Dimension
print(train_images.shape)

train_images1 = train_images[None,:,:,:]
#Add Dimension using None
print(train_images1.shape)

train_images2 = train_images[np.newaxis is None,:,:,:]
#Add dimension using np.newaxis
print(train_images2.shape)

#np.newaxis and none are same
np.newaxis is None
```

The Output of the above code is

```
2.1.0
(60000, 28, 28)
(1, 60000, 28, 28)
(1, 60000, 28, 28)
True
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was accepted: wasn't the question how to get a leading `None` dimension, rather than a leading `1` dimension? Is there a way to get a leading `None` instead of a `1`? I am asking for the same reason that @Benny K states, that it's required for TF graph creation and represents arbitrary batch size.

Answer (score 2):

In TF2 you can use tf.expand_dims:

```
xx = tf.expand_dims(xx, 0)
xx.shape
> TensorShape([1, 32, 32, 256])
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to simply add a "None" dimension.

However, assuming you are trying to prepend a variable-size batch dimension to your tensor, you can just `tf.repeat` your tensor using the `tf.shape()` of another tensor.

```py
y = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))   # Shape: [None, 32, 32, 3]
...
batch_size = tf.shape(y)[0]                    # Will be None initially, but is mutable
xx = tf.ones(shape=(32, 32, 356))              # Shape: [32, 32, 356]
xx = tf.expand_dims(xx, 0)                     # Shape: [1, 32, 32, 356]
xx = tf.repeat(xx, repeats=batch_size, axis=0) # Shape: [None, 32, 32, 356]
```

This will likely be more useful than just hard-coding the first dimension to `None` since what you probably actually want to be doing is copying it along that first dimension based on batch size.