# How to transform tensor with shape (4498,) to (None, 4498)?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to transform a tensor with shape (4498,) to a tensor with shape (None, 4498). I tried to reshape it, but it gives a tensor with shape (1, 4498). I tried a lot of other ways to transform it, but none of them worked. Any ideas?

```
print(info_state.get_shape()) #(4498,)
info_state = tf.reshape(info_state, [-1, 4498])
print(info_state.get_shape()) #(1, 4498)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add None dimension in tensorflow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486437/add-none-dimension-in-tensorflow-2-0)

Comment: @M.Innat I tried it before, but it didn't work. Tried it again and now it works.

Comment: That happens :p