# keep None dimension when slicing (tf.gather) a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, slice, tensor

I have a tensor of this shape [None,8], how can I slice it to get one sample and keep the "None" dimension? I use it in a sub-class model and don't want the bach size to be fixed.
What I expect: shape [None,1]

My best test

```
tf.expand_dims(tf.gather(tensor, 5, axis=1),0)
or
tensor[None,5]
```

but get this shape [1,1]

Comment: have u checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60486437/9215780
or, please provide minimum full code to clear your workflow.

Comment: tf.gather has a `batch_dims` argument exactly for this case, as long as your fine gathering the same indexes for each batch.

Answer (score 0):

as called by @Lescurel

tf.gather has a batch_dims argument exactly for this case, as long as your fine gathering the same indexes for each batch. –